# aws - how to store the file details using s3_direct_upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In rails 4.0.2, I am using `s3_direct_upload` gem to upload files directly to s3, after that I want to store the files & convert it to html, also I want to store some dependency files like converted `.html / .txt` files back to s3. But I am not able to get the files from s3 & also it is not saving to the database.

I have referred this from http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and.
How can I overcome this problem? awaiting for the solution.